# how to select the id of selectedIndex in jquery

Tags: jquery, select, indexing

I want to select the id of selectd item of a `dropdown` list in jquery

```
networkId = $("#availableFbProfiles").selectedIndex.id;
```

but the error on console is

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
networkId = $("#availableFbProfiles option:selected").prop("id");
```

If you're using an older version of jQuery (< 1.7) use `attr()` instead of `prop()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#availableFbProfiles option:selected").get(0).id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
networkId = $("#availableFbProfiles option:selected").prop("");
```